# Applet taking time to load in IE with java8u60

Tags: javascript, java, windows, internet-explorer

Applet is taking time to load after installing java 8 u60 in IE 9 and above. Earlier program was working fine. Now error thrown is TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method. I tried putting settimeout() this will solve the issue to some extent. I wonder why this behavior is observed only after upgrading to java8u60? Is there any other solution? Please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you recompiled your code using java 8u60?

Comment: Code is built using java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your code using java 8u60.

IMHO that should solve your problem.

Although jvms are backward compatible, java 8 have some major changes that may cause the described error.

If you need your applet being able to work in both java7 and java8, then

1. See if you have some compilation errors during compiling your code using java8.
2. Try to bypass those errors using java7-compatible api methods, and then rebuild it again in java7.

Comment: Tried compiling using java8u60, still its same.

Comment: @user1881297 Add full exception stack trace to your question, please.

Comment: Code snippet :
   try
   {
       var isInstalled = document.Installer.MsiInstalled();
   }
   catch(e)
   {
       alert(e.stack);
   }

Alert displays undefined.

Comment: @user1881297 You'd better add the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your question. It's also worth to read [this help page](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the applet was hidden and displayed on document load.
When I changed so that the applet is visible from the start it loaded quickly again.

Another case was caused by loading the applet in an iframe, and it was fixed by adding the applet to the iframe in the onload.

These problem only appeared in java8u60 and IE